# Determine mouse position outside of events (using jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, mouse, position

I need to get a hold of the absolute mouse position / coordinates (X and Y) using (preferably) jQuery like in [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position) but outside of any JavaScript event. Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Not possible. You can however use the same approach in the tutorial to store the position in a global variable and read it outside the event.

Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $().mousemove(function(e){
      window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
      window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;
   }); 
})
```

You can now use `window.mouseXPos` and `window.mouseYPos` from anywhere.

Comment: Is that a jQuery or JavaScript limitation?

Comment: @pbz It's a JavaScript limitation.

Comment: I just set up a jQuery.one('mousemove', function() {}); for this purpose. Delay it with a setTimeout, capture the mouse position the next time it moves, voila.

Comment: your answer is in an event, but the question is related the "outside of any JavaScript event"

Answer (score 29):

This started as a comment on [Chetan Sastry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133807/mouse-position-using-jquery-outside-of-events/1133854#1133854), but I realized it also might be worth posting as an answer:

I'd be careful about having a document-level, always-running `mousemove` event, even if you're only polling for cursor position. This is a lot of processing and can bog down any browser, particularly slower ones like IE.

A problem like this almost certainly raises the question of design decision: if you don't need to handle a mouse event to poll for the cursor position, do you really need the cursor position? Is there a better way to solve the problem you're trying to solve?

Edit: even in Safari 4, which is (understatement) **very fast**, that single `mousemove` event makes every interaction with that tutorial page noticeably choppy for me. Think about how that will affect users' perceptions of your site or application.

Comment: Not quite true.  A mouse event is ALWAYS being generated.  That is, when the mouse moves, the browser will compute (thru native code) a mouse event up to but not including executing JS callback functions; it's fundamental to ALL mouse related event listeners.  It is simply that the browser fails to provide the common courtesy of exposing that information except thru `document.onmousemove`.   This, as far as I'm concerned, is a shortsightedness of the ES5/ES6.   Indeed polling mouse position can simplify de-bouncing 'onmousemove' events, such as when moving DOM elements by mouse.

Comment: It will compute it for itself, but it won't compute the mousemove event and everything that depends on it unless something subscribes to it. That's just good sense.

Answer (score 10):

This function will decrease the impact on UI performance by only getting the mouse position at an interval:

```
function getMousePosition(timeoutMilliSeconds) {
    // "one" attaches the handler to the event and removes it after it has executed once 
    $(document).one("mousemove", function (event) {
        window.mouseXPos = event.pageX;
        window.mouseYPos = event.pageY;
        // set a timeout so the handler will be attached again after a little while
        setTimeout(function() { getMousePosition(timeoutMilliSeconds) }, timeoutMilliseconds);
    });
}

// start storing the mouse position every 100 milliseconds
getMousePosition(100);
```

Just as in the other answer "You can now use `window.mouseXPos` and `window.mouseYPos` from anywhere."

You lose a little accuracy as the mouse move won't be detected during the intervals.

Comment: You should avoid using eval-like constructs. They are less efficient, and are potential security risks. `setTimeout(function() { getMousePosition(timeoutMilliSeconds) }, timeoutMilliseconds);`

Answer (score 2):

I have try @Chetan Sastry 's soulution,but it does't works.(I'm using jQuery 1.6.4). I change the code and then i works now. Here is my code. I hope this will help.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
          window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;
       }); 
    });
```

Comment: Verified. This change also fixes for jQuery 1.4.4