# How to trigger mouseover/mouseout events when element rather than mouse is moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, mouseevent

By default, mouse related events are not triggered in javascript if the mouse is not actually moved, even if it is now inside/outside a target element (e.g., div or svg:rect) because of the movement of the element itself.

How to efficently handle this kind of state change?

### EDIT

There is a closely related question. However, that question seems not settled satisfactorily. Most answers propose to check whether the element is under the mouse **when** it moves, which really means **before** it moves. In my case, the target elements are complex svg:path, and there could be hundreds of them, thus making such prediction is not trivial.

Is there any way to tap on the browser's built-in mechanism (with which mouse events are triggered when the mouse is moving) to detect such events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hover not triggered when element is programatically moved under the mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403518/jquery-hover-not-triggered-when-element-is-programatically-moved-under-the-mouse)

Comment: Aha, indeed a duplication... Thanks, @DelightedD0D~ Now there should be more keywords pointing to the same question:)

Comment: Does this really not work nativel in Firefox. I thought this was fixed years ago (could have regressed I suppose).

Comment: I think you can read the x,y coordinates of the mouse and process the coordinates whether it is inside or outside your target. Hope this is what you meant.