# How to detect co-ordinates of mouse pointer over a div

Tags: jquery

Suppose there is a DIV with the following properties:

```
top:100;
left:100;
height:200;
width:200;
```

Now, when i position the mouse pointer in the browser at co-ords(105,210), it means that the mouse pointer is on the div at (5, 110). So this is the thing that i want to calculate using `jQuery`. Can anyone help me with some code suggestions?

Comment: Please notice that you always need to add a unit to the CSS-properties top, left, height and with. In this case you would need to add a 'px'. (I'm posting this as a comment because its not related to the question.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133807/mouse-position-using-jquery-outside-of-events

Comment: @andre_roesti: i forgot to mention the PXs. anyways, this question is more related to jQuery. The properties were just mentioned for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract the properties `offsetLeft` of your DIV from `pageX` and `offsetTop` from `pageY`.

```
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - $('#example').offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - $('#example').offsetTop;
}
```