# Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, mouse

I want a function that tells me which element the mouse cursor is over.

So, for example, if the user's mouse is over this textarea (with id `wmd-input`), calling `window.which_element_is_the_mouse_on()` will be functionally equivalent to `$("#wmd-input")`.

Answer (score 215):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MPTTp/)

There's a really cool function called `document.elementFromPoint` which does what it sounds like.

What we need is to find the x and y coords of the mouse and then call it using those values:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  console.clear()
  console.log( document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) )
}, {passive: true})
```

```css
[class^='level']{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #00000033;
}
```

```html
<div class='level-1'>
  <div class='level-2'>
    <div class='level-3'>
      Hover
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**document.elementFromPoint**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)

[**jQuery event object**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: This was what I thought of too, but I didn't know about `elementFromPoint` (and didn't bother looking :)). It's a cool function. Is it supported by all the major browsers?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Well from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259585/get-element-at-specified-position-javascript) I see it's supported on IE and firefox. If you get those two you usually get them all. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417%28VS.85%29.aspx) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: Awesome. It also works on Chrome (at least 16 on Linux). And I don't really care about Safari, but it probably works there too.

Comment: Awesome. Is there any way to get the coords of the mouse WITHOUT catching an event? (Probably not I assume). If this isn't possible, then unfortunately I don't think this method is any better than `event.target` or whatever

Comment: @HoraceLoeb It's not possible to get the mouse coords without catching an event.  see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133807/determine-mouse-position-outside-of-events-using-jquery) for further explanation

Comment: @HoraceLoeb It is possible using jQuery `$(':hover')`. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/2pks4tf6/

Comment: That's a weird way to do it. If you catch an event, why not just using `event.target` ?

Comment: Answer does not explain what `event` is, and how it came to be

Comment: This is in mousemove event. And you can't use event.target because that's undefined if the mouse isn't pressed. Even if the mouse is pressed, event.target stays as the element that the click started on.

Answer (score 89):

In newer browsers, you could do the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll( ":hover" );
```

That'll give you a NodeList of items that the mouse is currently over in document order.  The last element in the NodeList is the most specific, each preceding one should be a parent, grandparent, and so on.

Comment: This didn't seem to work while I was dragging an `<li>` while on top of other `<li>` elements.

Comment: I created a fiddle with `$(':hover')` but it's basically the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/2pks4tf6/

Comment: `(function(){ var q = document.querySelectorAll(":hover"); return q[q.length-1]; })()`

Comment: You'd be amazed at how many DOM traversals your computer can do while it waits for the incredibly slow human to move the mouse another pixel.

Answer (score 56):

Although the following may not actually answering the question, since this is the first result of googling (the googler may not asking exactly the same question:), hope it will provide some extra input.

There are actually two different approaches to get a list of all elements the mouse is currently over (for newer browsers, perhaps):

### The "structural" approach - Ascending DOM tree

As in [dherman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript/15263171#15263171), one can call

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
```

However, this assumes that only children will overlay their ancestors, which is usually the case, but not true in general, especially when dealing with SVG where element in different branches of the DOM tree may overlap each other.

### The "visual" approach - Based on "visual" overlapping

This method uses `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` to find the topmost element, temporarily hide it (since we recover it immediately in the same context, the browser will not actually renders this), then go on to find the second topmost element... Looks a little hacky, but it returns what you expect when there are, e.g., siblings elements in a tree occluding each other. Please find [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/567610-elements-below-point-under-cursor) for more details,

```
function allElementsFromPoint(x, y) {
    var element, elements = [];
    var old_visibility = [];
    while (true) {
        element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        if (!element || element === document.documentElement) {
            break;
        }
        elements.push(element);
        old_visibility.push(element.style.visibility);
        element.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Temporarily hide the element (without changing the layout)
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < elements.length; k++) {
        elements[k].style.visibility = old_visibility[k];
    }
    elements.reverse();
    return elements;
}
```

Try both, and check their different returns.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks @herrlich10. Surprisingly, your code handles the case with nested children elements as well.

Comment: This is extremely useful. Exactly what I was looking for. As you said, querySelectorAll doesn't work in every scenario.

Comment: @herrlich10 This seems like a decent polyfill for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint.  If that API exists in your supported browserSet, I think you could use that.

Comment: Thanks for this - works pretty much as expetced (though no elements.reverse for compat with getElementsFromPoint), but it is wayyy slower (18-20ms per call in my testing in chrome) which makes it hard to use in the scenario I had  in mind (finding drop targets during a drag in a case when using a more basic event-driven approach is not doable).

Comment: with the hacky approach, instead of hiding elements on the screen, you'd be better off just using document.elementFromPoint, then loop using element.parentNode, and finally, get the dimensions of the parent node and test the offset left & top position and width & height of the parent node against the cursor x & y.

Comment: I am using the "visual approach" and ended up in an endless loop, because i was using "pointer-events:all" on one of my elements. 
I fixed that by using  element.style.display = 'none' instead of "visibility:hidden"

Comment: BUG: ends up in infinite loop when the visibility is animated, eg. when `transition: all 1s`; is used

Comment: @herrlich10 What if you are moving an element, holding down the mouse and moving. Would :hover work then?

Comment: see `Document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31805883/1059828

Answer (score 27):

`elementFromPoint()` gets only the first element in DOM tree. This is mostly *not* enough for developers needs. To get more than one element at e.g. the current mouse pointer position, this is the function you need:

```
document.elementsFromPoint(x, y) . // Mind the 's' in elements
```

This returns an array of all element objects under the given point.
Just pass the mouse X and Y values to this function.

More information is here: *[DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementsFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/elementsFromPoint)*

For very old browsers which are not supported, you may use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884653) as a fallback.

Comment: It is well supported now in 2018.

Answer (score 10):

The following code will help you to get the element of the mouse pointer. The resulted elements will display in the console.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)); 
})
```

Comment: This requires the cursor to move. As close as it could be, it's not what is being asked here.

Comment: Doesn't work if the page is scrolled. Use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` instead (tested on Firefox 59).

Answer (score 8):

Mouseover events bubble, so you can put a single listener on the body and wait for them to bubble up, then grab the `event.target` or `event.srcElement`:

```
function getTarget(event) {
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
    return el.nodeType == 1? el : el.parentNode;
}

<body onmouseover="doSomething(getTarget(event));">
```

Comment: While I myself use universal event handlers this would be more expensive resource wise than `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can look at the target of the `mouseover` event on some suitable ancestor:

```
var currentElement = null;

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    currentElement = e.target;
});
```

[Here’s a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/acGxc/68/)

Answer (score 5):

#### Demo :D

Move your mouse in the snippet window :D

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    console.log ("You are in ", e.target.tagName);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- One simple solution to your problem could be like this: -->

<div>
<input type="text" id="fname" onmousemove="javascript: alert(this.id);" />
<!-- OR -->
<input type="text" id="fname" onclick="javascript: alert(this.id);" />
</div>
<!-- Both mousemove over the field & click on the field displays "fname"-->
<!-- Works fantastic in IE, FireFox, Chrome, Opera. -->
<!-- I didn't test it for Safari. -->
```

Comment: I apologise for the poor manner in which you were treated on your (now deleted) question. Personally I would prefer the question to be undeleted. Whilst it was on its way to being closed (unfairly, in my view), I was planning on voting to re-open it. However, given the number of downvotes, I understand if you choose to keep it deleted.

Answer (score 3):

### 2022 Update:

`document.elementsFromPoint()` (Note the 's' in elements) is compatible with all major browsers. It basically does the same thing that `elementFrompoint` does, but retrieves all the elements in DOM order.

Mozilla has a good example of this:

##### HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<p>Elements at point 30, 20:</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

##### JavaScript

```
let output = document.getElementById("output");
if (document.elementsFromPoint) {
  let elements = document.elementsFromPoint(30, 20);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    output.textContent += elements[i].localName;
    if (i < elements.length - 1) {
      output.textContent += " < ";
    }
  }
} else {
  output.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color: red;\">" +
     "Browser does not support <code>document.elementsFromPoint()</code>" +
     "</span>";
}
```

##### Output

```
Some text

Elements at point 30, 20:

p < div < body < html
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint

Answer (score 2):

You can use this selector to undermouse object and then manipulate it as a jQuery object:

```
$(':hover').last();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information. Also, "undermouse"?

Comment: What is *"to undermouse object"*? Do you mean *"to the under-the-mouse object"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The target of the `mousemove` DOM event is the top-most DOM element under the cursor when the mouse moves:

```
(function(){
    //Don't fire multiple times in a row for the same element
    var prevTarget=null;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        //This will be the top-most DOM element under cursor
        var target=e.target;
        if(target!==prevTarget){
            console.log(target);
            prevTarget=target;
        }
    });
})();
```

This is similar to @Philip Walton's solution, but doesn't require jQuery or a setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for those that may still be struggling. You want to add a `mouseover` event on the 'parent' element of the child element(s) you want detected. The below code shows you how to go about it.

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper') //parent element
const position = document.getElementById("displaySelection")

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let elementPointed = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)

  console.log(elementPointed)
});
```

**[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqRKww)**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. I wanted to add my solution in.

```
function pointerOverElement( element, { clientX: x, clientY: y } ){
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.left <= x && rect.right >= x && rect.top <= y && rect.bottom >= y;
}
```

then just use it in your events as:

```
pointerOverElement( element, e );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start out by saying that I don't recommend using the method I'm about to suggest. It's much better to use event driven development and bind events only to the elements you're interested in knowing whether or not the mouse is over with `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, etc.

If you absolutely *must* have the ability to know which element the mouse is over, you'd need to write a function that binds the `mouseover` event to everything in the DOM, and then store whatever the current element is in some variable.

You could so something like this:

```
window.which_element_is_the_mouse_on = (function() {

    var currentElement;

    $("body *").on('mouseover', function(e) {
        if(e.target === e.currentTarget) {
            currentElement = this;
        }
    });

    return function() {
        console.log(currentElement);
    }
}());
```

Basically, I've created an immediate function which sets the event on all elements and stores the current element within the closure to minimize your footprint.

Here's a working demo that calls `window.which_element_is_the_mouse_on` every second and logs what element the mouse is currently over to the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/LWFpJ/1/