# Check if element is hovered over in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can one check if the cursor is hovered over in jquery or js.

I have tried `$('#id').is(':hover')` but this doesnt seem to be working at all.

I have to mention that i am calling this line inside of a `hover()` function could this maybe be the problem?

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    /* On hover function, over the menu items */
    $('nav ul li').hover(function(){
        $('nav ul li').css("background-color", "");
        $('#append').css("background-color", "");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#9999FF"); 
        $('#append').css("background-color", "#9999FF"); 

        var append;
        if($('#menu-item-12')) {
            append = 'news';
        }else if($('#menu-item-9:hover')) {
            append = 'account';
        }else if($('#menu-item-11').is(':hover')) {
            append = 'check out';
        }
        $('#appendp').empty();
        $('#appendp').append(document.createTextNode(append));

    });
```

Hope someone can tell me whats wrong.

here is jsfiddle link, i did my best :) https://jsfiddle.net/xsv325ef/

Comment: Can you put that on jsFiddle, Codepen ect...

Comment: @esc sure i can, just one second

Comment: Are menu items `li`?

Comment: Why don't you try it separately outside the hover function and please put the jsfiddle/codepen whatever

Comment: Are you trying to do something along these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/3ype31sp/1

Comment: Now it's clear you forget to add `});` on the last line to close your `$(document.ready())` function.

Comment: The better way for doing this kind of checks is in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript), please have a check and you'll get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check if hovered item has this id.

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hrskgxz5/5/

```
 if(this.id === 'menu-item-11') {
     append = 'check out';
     alert('hovered');
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly, do you know maybe why my method failed?

Comment: there is no point of checking if  an item is hovered. there is an event "on('mouseover')". You never check that item is clicked like (if item.is('click')), same goes for hover.

Answer (score 4):

A nice way to do it is to store the related texts into an Object literal,
and recall the text depending on the hovered element ID:

***[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xsv325ef/2/)***

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand ;)

    var $appendEl = $('#appendp');
    var id2text = {
        "menu-item-12" : "unlock this crap",
        "menu-item-9"  : "check your gdmn account",
        "menu-item-11" : "check the hell out"
    };

    $('nav ul li').hover(function(){
        $appendEl.text( id2text[this.id] );
    });

});
```

Regarding the colors... use CSS `:hover`

Comment: This is a perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('li').hover(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "#9999FF");          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I hope this helps understand how to hover logic works

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that jQuery `.hover()` function takes 2 handler function, and here you only provide one. Check the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) here.

In your case, you may just use `.mouseover()` to add a class on top of it, and then set your styles in css file. ([Document here](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/))

For example:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  $('nav ul li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

If you do need to toggle the class for that element, the hover function should be as follow:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  $('nav ul li').hover(function() {
    // Stuff to do when the mouse enters the element
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Other styles you want to do here
    // ...

  }, function() {
    // Stuff to do when the mouse leaves the element
    $(this).removeClass('active');

    // Other styles you want to remove here
    // ...

  });
});
```

### Edit:

As I found out, jQuery `.hover()` function DO accept single handler. In that case, you'll have to let the class toggle inside:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  $('nav ul li').hover(function() {
    // Stuff to do when the mouse enters the element
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

  });
});
```