# jQuery UI draggable: get the underlaying element at drag-stop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-draggable

Is it possible to get the underlaying element of an dragged element?

My specific task is to drag a `td` element. If the dragstop event is fired I want the underlaying element. The underlaying element is also a `td`.

How could I achiev this?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="grid">
     <tr>
         <td class="value" colspan="4"></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery part is here:

```
$('.value').draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    containment: ".grid",
    snap: "td",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("start", event, ui, $(this));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("stop", event, ui, $(this));
    }
});
```

If I drag the `td` with the class `value` and I stop dragging I want the `td` element under the value element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a neat little function wich will find you the element on a specific function: `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

On SO I found a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884653/4202224) to determine **all** elements on that position. I refer to this answer in my code:

```
$('.value').draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    containment: ".grid",
    snap: "td",
    start: function(event, ui) {
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

        var el = allElementsFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        var td = $(el).filter('td').not($(this));
        td.css({'backgroundColor': 'red'});
    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fxz49bf0/2/)**

So the function will return all elements that lies at the specified position. To get the wanted `td` filter the elements to only contain `td`s and remove the dragged `td`.

**Reference**

[.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I modified it a bit and it works like a charme!

Comment: v.good solution... but sometimes it returns -1 value of  `var td` **please fix this issue** @empiric