# How to make elements with high z-index allow click events at elements below?

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension, z-index

I'm developing a chrome extension. It is basically a toolbar standing at the upper part of the visible screen, added to the page as an Iframe.

My problem is that I set it a high `z-index` to make sure the bar appears; and then the elements below it (below the Iframe) gets not clickable (lets say I got a piece of the iFrame that is transparent, what allows the user to see the elements below it). Other Stack Overflow questions doesn't address my problem, since they suppose I have control at both the upper and the lesser elements, and I don't have at the lesser one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only certain parts of the iframe should let the clicks pass through then in the iframe's onclick handler send a message to the content script of the page via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) with the click point coordinates and in the content script's `document.addEventListener` for that message use [`querySelectorAll(':hover')` or `document.elementFromPoint` while temporarily hiding the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884653/3959875) to find the clicked element and then dispatch a new `click` event to that element via [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) (plus the iframe's top-left corner offset in the original document).

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain it better? Who sends and who receives the message? And do I really need to hide the Iframe?

Comment: Not sure how I can explain it better without implementing the whole thing myself. As for hiding it's only one method and it won't be noticeable I think because it'll be done just for the duration of the function call.

Comment: Well, let me see if I can make a better question: you tell of a "content script of the page" and a "content script's document.addEventListener". But I got just one content script archive. Can I suppose both this quotes relates to the same script?

Comment: Yes, I mean your extension's content script that runs on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this simply by using CSS

```
pointer-events: none
height: 0px;
overflow: visible;
```

Comment: This will work in all browsers except in IE 10 and below unfortunately, Javascript would be the best solution for that i'm afraid

Comment: Yes, but I need the bar to be clickable! And if I set this property to the whole Iframe, I can't make anything inside it clickable anymore!

Comment: a little hack should work:
height:0px;
overflow:visible;

ofcourse with:
pointer-events: none;

Comment: You can “reverse” it on inner/descendant elements, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Notes

Comment: iframe's content document isn't an inner/descendant element.

Comment: Also `height:0` on iframe will collapse it even with the `overflow:visible` because iframes don't have intrinsic height.

Comment: @hreitsma I think it does not works in this case, since it is an Iframe!