# How can i get the element tag in HTML using the location get by scroll function

Tags: javascript, scroll

I know how to get window location from the scroll function with javascript.
But when I got the window location or px, How can I find  the element tag name? Thanks

Comment: yes, dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript

Comment: @AndrewEvt Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

```
 <span id="myP">Click the button to display the tag name of this element.</span>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").tagName;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

You will get result:  SPAN

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Thanks but, i want to know element tag from the scroll location in browser.