# Hover the element below the mouse cursor when scrolling

Tags: javascript, events

One can determine the element below the mouse cursor (i.e. the top-most hovered element) with the following techniques:

- Listen for the `mousemove` event. The target is

  - `event.target` **or**
  - `document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)`.

This does not work when scrolling *while not moving the mouse*. Then, the mouse technically doesn’t move; thus, no mouse event will fire.

Unfortunately, both techniques from above are no longer applicable when listening for the `scroll` event. `event.target` will be whichever element is scrolled (or `document`). Also, the mouse cursor position is not exposed on the `event` object.

As described in [this answer to “Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884653/2036825), one possible solution is querying the hovered element via the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const hoverTarget = document.querySelector('.element:hover');
  if (hoverTarget) {
    hover(hoverTarget);
  }
});
```

However, this is not usable because it is very inefficient and inaccurate. The `scroll` event is one of the rapidly firing events and needs to be slowed down when performing anything mildly costly (e.g. querying the DOM).

Also, the hovered element *lags behind* when scrolling. You can observe this on any kind of website with a lot of links: Hover over one of them and scroll to another link without moving the mouse. It updates only after a few milliseconds.

Is there any way, this can be implemented nicely and efficient? Basically, I want the inverse of `mouseenter`: Instead of knowing when the mouse enters and element, I want to know when an element intersects with the mouse (e.g. when the mouse is not moved but the element [i.e. when scrolling]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach of tackling this is storing the mouse cursor location with the `mousemove` event and in the `scroll` event use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` to figure out the element that should be hovered.

Keep in mind that this is still pretty inefficient due to the `scroll` event being fired with such a high frequency. The event handler should be *debounced* to limit execution of the function to once per delay. David Walsh explains how to do this in [JavaScript Debounce Function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

```js
let hoveredElement;
let mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;

    hover(event.target);
  });

  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const hoverTarget = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (hoverTarget) {
      hover(hoverTarget);
    }
  });
});

function hover(targetElement) {
  // If the target and stored element are the same, return early
  // because setting it again is unnecessary.
  if (hoveredElement === targetElement) {
    return;
  }

  // On first run, `hoveredElement` is undefined.
  if (hoveredElement) {
    hoveredElement.classList.remove('hover');
  }

  hoveredElement = targetElement;
  hoveredElement.classList.add('hover');
}
```

```css
.element {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}

.element.hover {
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element-1">1</div>
  <div class="element element-2">2</div>
  <div class="element element-3">3</div>
  <div class="element element-4">4</div>
  <div class="element element-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Currently, the solution will hover the top-most element under the mouse both when moving the mouse and when scrolling. It might be more suitable for your needs to attach the `mousemove` listener to a set of specific elements and then always hover `event.currentTarget` (i.e. the element the event listener was attached to). As for the `scroll` part, you can use `hoverTarget.closest` to find the suitable element up in the DOM tree.

Comment: In this solution you have overcome the problem of scrolling while the mouse is not moving. On scroll, the "under-the-pointer" element is indeed receiving a `hover` class. However, wouldn't you want this `hover` class to be applied on `mousemove` as well?