# CodeMirror getCursor node?

Tags: codemirror

How do I get situation of cursor's node?

[image]

```html
<span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
  <span class="cm-strong">**dfgdf fghh trth**</span>
</span>
```

I am writing a markdown **toolbar**.

I try to find out text at current cursor postion is bold or not.

pseudocode:

```
if cursorNode is bold
  remove bold
else
  add bold
```

I expect something like `getCurrorNode` API exist, but just can't find this API.

---

```js
let cursorPos = editor.getCursor();
editor.getTokenAt(cursorPos); //only get a word
```

**token** only get a word, not a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

`document.elementFromPoint` + codemirror's `cursorCoords`:

```js
document.elementFromPoint(cm.cursorCoords(cm.getCursor()).left, 
                          cm.cursorCoords(cm.getCursor()).top);
```

ref: 
[Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript)

---

there are still one problem:
This is a **fake change**.
Even you change this element, it doesn't reflect on actually cm. Once you type a random character on this line, the original sentence come back!